# LTI1.3 tool provider implementation with Zend 2

Tags: php, lti

How to implement LTI1.3 as a tool provider in my learning app. I have tried php LTI1.3 library available in GitHub but not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

1. Use the IMS certified LTIJS library for JavaScript/express: https://github.com/Cvmcosta/ltijs which is easier to set up and configure compared to the PHP library, IMHO.
2. If you don't want to deal with rolling your own LTI provider, it might be easier to just use an LTI service provider and use a simple RESTful API: https://ltiaas.com can help you do this and guarantee LTI/IMS compliance.

*Disclaimer, I am the CEO of LTIAAS.*